# .net Web Api routing not respected

Tags: routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have inherited a web api project. It was v2.1 but have now upgraded to v2.2

However, when I try to add an attribute route to a controller is is not respected

I have created a new API controller that looks like this

```
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("test")]
    public int TestInt()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

my routing looks like this

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "{controller}/{id}",
        defaults: new { action = RouteParameter.Optional, id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

however when I hit the /test url I get this

```
<Error>
<Message>
No HTTP resource was found that matches the request URI 'https://localhost:446/test'.
</Message>
<MessageDetail>
No type was found that matches the controller named 'test'.
</MessageDetail>
</Error>
```

Have tried with various combinations of route but nothing seems to work

I have tried exactly the same in another project and it works fine

So I presume there is something in this project preventing the routing from working

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you should add the RoutePrefix attribute over your controller:

```
[RoutePrefix("test")]
public class MyController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public int TestInt()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}
```

Also yo should add the next line in your WebApiConfig:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
```

I hope that it helps.

Comment: thanks - I was missing the webapiconfig setting
I also needed a [HttpGet] on the action - it doesnt seem to work without it

The route prefix is not necessary, btw. But a good idea anyway